# How to calculate to angle of two 90 degree in a triangle, to find last angle

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to calculate the angle v in this triangle

[image: What I want]

By first making a 90 line with the length of r.

[image: First take]

Then I need to make a similar line on the other side of the triangle like shown below.

[image: Result]

But I need to do this by calculate the angle between the two lines. (v) so that the second line connect to the side of the triangle with a 90 degree angle. So I need to get this line, by calculate v with the data I got like shown below

[image: What I got]

The angle of the triangle(30 degrees here). Will always be 90 degrees or under.

As always, thanks for your time.

Comment: sry, i normally only ask programming question, so i only been using this forum. and forgot that there was other topic forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's not a triangle - it's a special quadrilateral - deltoid or kite (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kite_%28geometry%29).

You know 3 angle of this deltoid:
- 30
- 90 (straight angle is 180 - minus your known 90)
- again
You can calculate the missing angle:
Internal angle for this poligon 360 minus your known 30 minus your calculated 90 twice = 150

Generally - if the known angle is 'a'
the missing angle is v=360-a-2*90=180-a
because the summa of all ange is 360 (360=90+90+a+v) in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The total internal angle for a polygon is (n-2)180°, where n is the number of sides. You are forming a quadrilateral, therefore there is a total internal angle of 360°. After removing the 180° from the two right angles and the 30° from the original angle you are left with 150°.

Answer (score 0):

Join the vertex where the 30 degree angle is to the vertex with the angle v. Now you have two congruent right triangles with one 15 degree angle so the other angle in one of these triangles is 90-15=75 degrees which is half of your angle v. So angle v is 150 degrees.